# How to declare a variable number of indexed strings?

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to declare multiple variables and the number of variables to declare depends on an input so it is something like:

```
Sub Main()
Dim TotalNumber As Long
    TotalNumber = InputBox("Please enter total number of words")
Dim i As Long
Dim MsgDisp As String
Dim Words(1 To TotalNumber) As String
For i = 1 To TotalNumber
    String(i) = InputBox("Please type the words for number " & i)
    MsgDisp = MsgDisp & String(i) & Chr(10)
Next i
MsgBox(MsgDisp)
End Sub
```

I however got the "Constant expression required" Error at Line 6.
Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is by first declaring the array without bounds and then redimming it:

```
Dim Words() As String
'Other code
ReDim Words(1 To TotalNumber)
```

During the further course of your code you can even expand the array. But to avoid the array being zapped, you add the Preserve keyword:

```
TotalNumber = TotalNumber + 1
ReDim Preserve Words(1 To TotalNumber)
```

Edited to remove "As String" after the redims. Edited again to add the Preserve keyword.

Comment: Thank you! That does it. I did not know the size has to be separately defined.

Answer (score 0):

Should be Words(i) i think.  Not String.  Also, i dont think that you're dim will accept a variable that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sub:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim TotalNumber As Long
            TotalNumber = Val(InputBox("Please enter total number of words"))
        Dim i As Long
        Dim MsgDisp As String
        Dim Words() As String
        ReDim Words(TotalNumber)
        For i = 1 To TotalNumber
            Words(i) = InputBox("Please type the words for number " & i)
            MsgDisp = MsgDisp & Words(i) & Chr(10)
        Next i
        MsgBox MsgDisp
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have to re-size array length with `ReDim` like `ReDim Words(TotalNumber)`.